# showing ERROR: Failed to resolve: exifinterface

Tags: android, picasso

I want to add picasso library but it shows this Error:
ERROR: Failed to resolve: exifinterface,why?

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
   implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.1.0"
}
```

Or a newer version.

As Picasso has dependencies to exifinterface.

Comment: I added this line to dependency but again shows same error.

Comment: Does your app have more than one modules? Maybe the dependency is missing on another different module than the one you've added it or in multiple modules. Could it be?

Comment: No,it has one module.

Comment: And you are using the jetpack androidx on yoir app, right? Because with the old support lib the exifinterface package was different

Comment: Yes, I'm using androidx on my app.